# "Cannot resolve TargetName Border" error wp8

Tags: xaml, exception, animation, windows-phone-8

Hi I have created an animation when a user presses any buttons on a page. using the code below. It simply uses a pivoting animation when it's pressed and also disables the standard blue background color of the button when pressed.

But I'm getting the exception "Cannot resolve TargetName Border"! see //<<<-----THIS in code below!?

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonBaseControlTemplate1" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">//<<<<-----THIS
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong here? I'm still pretty new to MS programming and would appreciate some help with this.

J

EDIT: I am assuming the above code is the culprit?

Comment: It should be obvious -- there's no element named "Border".  Did you mean to write "ButtonBackground"?

Comment: @McGarnagle Thanks, obvious now!

Comment: @McGarnagle I have replaced the "Border" with "ButtonBackground" but now I have the default colored background when the button is pressed!? What have I done wrong here - HELP thanks